# Hide and Enable set of Div with same class name in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to hide the all the div with same class name except first div. And then each button click I have to enable other div one by one in js.

```
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <div class ="TextDiv">1</div>
    <div class ="TextDiv">2</div>
    <div class ="TextDiv">3</div>
    <div class ="TextDiv">4</div>
    <div class ="TextDiv">5</div>
 <input type="submit" value="Show more" onClick>

<script>
function myFunction() {

}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Hezron - you need to say in your question what you have tried so far, and why it is not working. Stack Overflow is not a site where people will design and write your code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the first `<div />` in your jQuery selector:

```
$(".TextDiv:not(:first)")
```

You are still selecting all the `<div />` with the class `TextDiv` but removing the first one with the `:not(:first)` part of the selector.

You'll then be able to hide, show or toggle the elements (except the first one).

```
// Show all except first one
$(".TextDiv:not(:first)").show();

// Hide all except first one
$(".TextDiv:not(:first)").hide();

// Toggle all except first one
$(".TextDiv:not(:first)").toggle();
```

You can check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4v6tazh/) for an example. All `<div />` except the first one are hidden for example.

Regarding the "Show more" button, you can fetch the last `<div />` visible with the `TextDiv` class, go to the next one and show it:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $(".TextDiv:visible").last().next().show();
});
```

You can check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbvum34v/1/) for an example. All `<div />` except the first one are hidden, a click on the "Show more" button will show the other `<div />` one by one.

If you want to show multiple `<div />` at each button press, one approach could be to select all the hidden `<div />` with the `TextDiv` class, select only the first `x` ones using the `slice` function and then show them. For example, to show the 5 next hidden ones:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $(".TextDiv:hidden").slice(0, 5).show();
})
```

You can check [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/4f9urah0/2/) on JSFiddle showing the hidden `<div />` five-by-five each time you press the "Show more" button.

Comment: @HiDeo This answers seems to be working fine. Can you explain how can I do his for multiple div. For example there are 20 divs with same class name. Initially I load first 5 divs and each button click I have to enable next 5 div?

Comment: I added an example to my answer regarding how to show multiple div each time you press the "Show more" button @HezronNaresh

Comment: @HiDeo, you're absolutely ruthless. When don't have a good reason to downvote a question, you shouldn't be doing it "just because I want to."

Answer (score 0):

The :not(selector) selector matches every element that is NOT the specified element/selector.
Try this Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".TextDiv:not(:first)").css("display","none");
    $('input [type="submit"]').click(function(){

    $('.TextDivdiv:hidden:first').css("display","block");

    });
    });
```